# How bad is it to broadcast the access token in a SPA PKCE flow?

Tags: oauth, single-page-application, pkce, broadcast-channel

I have implemented a PKCE-flow for my SPA. I'd like to keep the SPA state "alive", and not have the browser leave the SPA, go to the STS, and then come back into the SPA. I therefore use an IFRAME.

This brings me the challenge of communicating the received access code on the callback URL (the IFRAME) to the SPA application. Already using the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) in other parts of my application, I found that communicating it over this channel to the SPA works very well.

I know that an SPA is untrusted, and I always treat it as such. This is why we have refresh tokens. As far as I can reason, the broadcast is no extra risk. But I am not so sure about the broadcasting channel itself, maybe it could be eavesdropped on? But even if it is, the refresh-token mechanic deals with leaking of the access token, right?

[image: PKCE flow]

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your flow:

- Requests during the STS authentication flow are protected by a cookie. When running in an iframe this will be categorized as cross-site and is likely to be dropped according to [RFC6265bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/#section-5.2). In a same domain employment you'll be be OK though.
- Cross site scripting vulnerabilities can enable malicious code to intercept the access token in the same way your code does. The [OAuth for Browser Based Apps Doc](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-17.html#section-5) has a section on JavaScript threats and XSS exploits.

For example, if you had an XSS exploit, malicious code could create its own BroadcastChannel onMessage handler, capture an access token and potentially exfiltrate it from the browser, for a more concerted attack against your APIs. Stakeholders could ask difficult questions about such threats.

These days users are socialized to being redirected to login. Also, if you use HTTP-only cookies rather than tokens in the browser your app will be perceived to be more secure. One option is to use a utility API to issue cookies on behalf of the SPA, eg the token handler pattern.

Comment: For your first point; the STS runs on the same domain, but not subdomain, as the SPA host (auth.example.com, www.example.com), if that matters? I did not receive any complaints by the browser, but only tested on Chrome. Will retry on Safari. For your 2nd point, this is what I meant by not trusting the SPA. It's probably not too hard for an attacker to insert whatever code it wants into an SPA and retrieve the access code; this is what I meant by the broadcast not being a new security risk. Thanks for taking your time to answer. Not heard of the token handler pattern, will look into that!

Comment: Went through the "OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps" document. **A Must Read for everybody doing anything with SPA auth!** My project lucky doesn't deal with any sensitive data and has little potential for abuse. For now we're going to keep it simple and only move to BFF if/when the project grows in usage. (I am not going to mark this answer as the accepted answer, as good as it is, as it doesn't strictly answer the Broadcast API question.)